# Django Error: Ensure this value has at most 10 characters (it has 321)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

i have page file that i am update the details of the user. (Student User)
and i create field for student:

> ID = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

and i also do clean_ID in StudentForm, but when i press the correct amount of characters
i got the this error:

> Ensure this value has at most 10 characters (it has 321).

you can see this in the photo down here.
i don't understand how to fix the problem.

VIEWS FILE

```
   class DetailsStudentView(View):
      def get(self,request, student_id):
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        userStudent = User.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        form_student = StudentForm(request.POST or None, instance=student)
        form_user = StudentUserUpdate(None,instance=userStudent)
        return render(request, "details.html",{'form_student':form_student, 'form_user':form_user})
      
  def post(self,request,student_id):
    form_student = StudentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form_student.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        email = form_student.cleaned_data['email']
        user.email = email
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
        student.first_name = form_student.cleaned_data['first_name']
        student.last_name = form_student.cleaned_data['last_name']
        student.Phone = form_student.cleaned_data['Phone']
        img = request.POST.get('imag_profile')
        if img != None:
          student.imag_profile = img
        student.ID = form_student.cleaned_data['ID']
        student.save()
        return redirect('HomePage:home')
    userStudent = User.objects.get(pk=student_id)
    form_user = StudentUserUpdate(None,instance=userStudent)   
    return render(request,'details.html',{'form_student':form_student, 'form_user':form_user})
```

Form FILE

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type':"text" ,'class': "bg-light form-control" }))
    class Meta():
      model = Student
      fields = ('first_name','last_name','Phone','imag_profile','ID')
      widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type':"text" ,'class':"bg-light form-control", }),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type':"text" ,'class':"bg-light form-control", }),
        'Phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type':"text" ,'class':"bg-light form-control", }),
        'ID': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'type':"text" ,'class':"bg-light form-control", }),
      }

    def clean_ID(self):
      ID = self.cleaned_data.get('ID')
      if not ID.isdecimal():
        raise forms.ValidationError("ID must to contain only digits.")
      elif len(ID) != 9:
        raise forms.ValidationError("ID must to contain 9 digits.")
      return self.cleaned_data
```

HTML FILE

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="wrapper bg-white mt-sm-5">
        <h4 class="pb-4 border-bottom">Account settings</h4>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-start py-3 border-bottom"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1037995/pexels-photo-1037995.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" class="img" alt="">
            <div class="pl-sm-4 pl-2" id="img-section"> 
                <label for="imag_profile"><b>Profile Photo</b></label>
                <p>Accepted file type .png. Less than 1MB</p> 
                {{form_student.imag_profile}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="py-2">
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <label for="first_name">שם פרטי</label> 
                    {{form_student.first_name}} 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-md-0 pt-3"> 
                    <label for="last_name">שם משפחה</label>
                    {{form_student.last_name}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <label for="email">מייל המכללה</label> 
                    {{form_user.email}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 pt-md-0 pt-3"> 
                    <label for="Phone">מספר פלאפון</label>  
                    {{form_student.Phone}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2">
                <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <label for="ID">תעודת זהות</label> 
                    {{form_student.ID}}
                    {% if form_student.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        {{form_student.ID.errors}}
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>

            <div class="py-3 pb-4 border-bottom"> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Save Changes</button> 
                <a href="{% url 'HomePage:home'%}" class="btn border button">Cancel</a>
                <a href="{% url 'Details:ch-pass' request.user.id %}" class="changePass">שינוי סיסמא</a>
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center pt-3" id="deactivate">
                <div> 
                    <b>Deactivate your account</b>
                    <p>Details about your company account and password</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-auto"> 
                   <a href="{% url 'Details:delete-user' request.user.id %}" class="btn danger">Delete User</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

i am also delete the db and make
makemigrations
and
migrate

but steel i got this problem.

Comment: I think your `clean_id` needs to return just the field, not the whole cleaned_data dictionary. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute `return ID` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

> Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if this
> method didn't change it. The return value of this method replaces the existing value in cleaned_data, so it must be the field’s value from cleaned_data (even if this method didn’t change it) or a new cleaned value.

So for your case, you probably want to amend `clean_id` to the following to return the value, not all of `cleaned_data`:

```
def clean_ID(self):
  ID = self.cleaned_data.get('ID')
  if not ID.isdecimal():
    raise forms.ValidationError("ID must to contain only digits.")
  elif len(ID) != 9:
    raise forms.ValidationError("ID must to contain 9 digits.")
  # return self.cleaned_data   # <--- DON'T DO THIS
  return ID
```